# Sequence of occurrences in Euler $\phi$ function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, totient-function

Let $a_n$ denote the number of positive integers $m$ such that $\phi(m) = n$, where $\phi$ denotes Euler's totient function.  The first several terms of the sequence, excluding zeros, are given by

$$\{a_n\} = \{2,3,4,4,5,2,6,6,4,5,2,10,2,\dotsc\}.$$

I would like to continue the sequence to $1,\!000$ terms.

> Q: What are the first thousand terms of the sequence in comma separated form? Does this sequence have any interesting properties?

Comment: The sequence is in the OEIS [here](https://oeis.org/A014197). A related sequence is [this](https://oeis.org/A032447).

Comment: does every value being greater than 1 count ? interest is subjective.

Comment: It seems like there are no $m$ so that $\phi(m)=3,$ or more generally for $n$ odd and $>1.$ How come your sequence doesn't include zero values?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews because they don't occur in the euler phi function

Comment: But it looks like, from your definition, $a(1)=2,a(2)=3,a(3)=4,a(4)=5,\dots$ which is not what you want. $a(n)$ is the number of times when $n$ occurs in the sequence, then $a(3)=0,$ not that $a(3)$ is skipped.

Comment: 3907 is the 1000th included number for counts  by coding. numbers that are totients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it has interesting properties:

- $\varphi(a\cdot b)= \gcd(a,b)\cdot \varphi({a\over\gcd(a,b)})\cdot \varphi({b\over\gcd(a,b)})$

Being the most important here. It allows conclusions like:

- if $c$ is odd, then $2c$  has the same totient value as $c$
- if $c$ is even, and $c$ is not divisible by 3, then $2c$ has the same totient value as $3c$
- if $c$ is divisible by 6, but not divisible by 5, then $4c$ has the same totient value as $5c$
- etc.